# Image saved in android is low quality

Tags: android, image, android-camera

I've been trying to take a photo and send it to my server in my android app. I know that this question was asked multiple times here, but I couldn't figure a way to integrate the solutions properly into my code, as it seems; all if the pictures I take are low quality (50K, thumbnail as I understood?). My code is as following:

```
    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        try {
            File file = createImageFile();//new File(getImageFileName());
            FileOutputStream fOS = new FileOutputStream(file);
            //TODO TEST PNG OR JPEG
            imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOS );
            Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
            this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

            AsyncTaskHTTP asyncTaskHTTP = new AsyncTaskHTTP("Image");
            asyncTaskHTTP.execute();
        }
        catch (Exception e){

        }
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "User" + ID + "Image" + imageCounter + "_" + timeStamp;
    imageCounter++;
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    String path = storageDir.getPath() + "/ALUMA";
    File temp = new File(path);
    temp.mkdirs();
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".png",         /* suffix */
            temp      /* directory */
    );
    currentImagePath = image.getPath();
    return image;
}
```

I saw that I need to add a file URI somewhere? or is there an easier way (I've tried to add a file's uri but the app simply crashed when I tried to take a picture)?